# Digitally sign large XML file

Tags: c#

I have large XML file to sign. The file size might go up to 4 GB. I am looking for solution where instead of loading whole document in to memory, I can do the signing batch by batch. Like reading few lines from stream and then sign it separately. Then combine all generated hash and compute final hash.

I am not much aware about hashing stuff. IF anybody knows the answer please help me?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what `sign` alludes to here.

Comment: Hashing and Digital Signing are two different processes.Most Hasing Algorithms have the basic feature that they are iterative(SHA,MD5 and so on) The algorithm itself will divide the large date block to chunks and apply function to each block pass on and finally get the final hash.Clearly describe what you want.

Comment: Hello I want to sign the XML file and to do so I have to using signing algorithm like RSA-SHA256.